# Using Laravel functions inside a javascript file that is included as an asset

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Let's say I have a piece of jQuery javascript that binds to a **div** on load and dynamically defines an **img** in that div. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").html("<img href='/images/myimage.jpg/>');
});
```

If I were to use this inlined in a Laravel view, I'd be able to use **HTML::image()** and Blade templates to specify the location of image. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").html("{{ HTML::image('images/myimage.jpg', 'My image') }}");
});
```

If I were then to take that piece of javascript, and, instead of inlining it in the view, place it inside a separate .js file, say, **public/js/image.js**, I could have Laravel load it as an asset;

```
Asset::add('image.js', 'js/image.js');
```

However, since it's now treated only as an asset, neither the Laravel PHP nor the Blade templating code is processed, so we literally get the string **{{ HTML::image('images/myimage.jpg', 'My image') }}** in the resulting html, instead of the templated-in values.

Is there a good approach for something like this?

Comment: Not without sending it to the server so you could run it through the Blade parser and get the parsed string back. Or you could just use raw HTML, as you showed in your first code example.

Comment: Are you only asking this to get the base URL appended?

Comment: I just chose the specifics for the example. A general accepted technique would be useful.

Comment: Generally - don't mix php and JS.  If you need to pass values to a JS script either output it as a meta/link tag in your HTML, or write some javascript out to the page that does such config - like google analytics might.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing this here. The way I found was:

1 - create a 'js' file inside the view directory tree, something like

```
app\views\javascript\mycustomJS.blade.php
```

2 - then render it wherever you need:

```
<script>
    @include('javascript.mycustomJS')
</script>
```

It's blade, it will be processed as it should.

This is far from ideal, I know, but it works for me, for now. :)

Comment: I'm using you solution right now. Did you find any better way of solving this problem? btw Thank your for the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put it in a php file. I've done this before with css.

```
Asset::add('image.php', 'js/image.php');
```

Comment: No. This doesn't work. CSS may be included with this technique, but a PHP file is still not parsed as a PHP file.